# R-Shiny error: "renderDataTable" and "server=FALSE"

Tags: r, shiny, dt

My app uses

```
drop_download(path = path1, local_path = path2)
d <<- read.csv(path2)
```

to read the data.frame, d, where d is a global variable (though I am not sure whether this piece of information is relevant).

And I have

```
output$t <- DT::renderDataTable(d, server=FALSE)
```

which throws an error:

```
Error: C stack usage  15923744 is too close to the limit
```

However, if I comment `server=FALSE` then it runs smoothly.

Could anyone explain what is going on and what the implications of commenting out `server=FALSE`?

Answer (score 4):

This is explained in `?renderDT`. With `server = FALSE`, all the data are sent to the client-side (the browser), while only the displayed data are sent to the browser with `server = TRUE`. You get an error because your dataset is too big, and sending it entirely to the browser would slow down the app or even crash it. Using `server = FALSE` can simplify some things, for example you don't need to use a proxy when you edit some cells. But if you don't modify the table contents (editing the cells for example), using `server=TRUE` does not cause any complication.

Comment: thanks @Stéphane Laurent, but I think my dataset is pretty small: 'data.frame': 24 obs. of 5 variables. Size should not be the reason for this error.

Comment: @armtar Indeed, this is not the error message thrown by `renderDT`. There should be a problem elsewhere. Have you tried the app after restarting RStudio ? Can you post the full code ?